# Floating point operation in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point

I have questions about the floating point number operations in x86 assembly.

With Irvine library, I use `ReadFloat` to read two floating point numbers from the user, and store each number in `fpA` and `fpB`.

When I add them by using `FADD`, it doesn't work. For example:

```
call ReadFloat
mov fpA, eax
call ReadFloat
mov fpB, eax
fadd fpA, fpB
mov eax, fpA
call WriteFloat
```

Above code fails, same thing goes with subtraction, multiplication, division...

It also gives me an error for having:

```
fpA REAL32 ? ; A2008: syntax error: REAL32
fpB REAL32 ? ; A2008: syntax error: REAL32
```

Please help me with this. How can I fix the syntax error and how can I do the basic four math operations with two floating point numbers?

Comment: There's no `fadd m32fp, m32fp` instruction. If you're going to program in assembly you need to have the instruction set reference, i.e. _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual_ so you can look things up.

Comment: Regarding `REAL32`, you haven't mentioned which assembler you're using, but I'm going to guess MASM. I don't see anything about `REAL32` in the MASM documentation, but there's a `REAL4` for 32-bit single-precision floats.

Comment: Are you sure ReadFloat returns in EAX?  That would be weird.  If the ReadFloat in https://gist.github.com/soachishti/a4d7bb15ee6519f61c0a matches whatever you're using, it returns in `st0`, the top of the x87 stack.  (x87 is mostly obsolete; normally you'd want to use `movss xmm0, [fpA]` / `addss xmm0, [fpB]` or similar.)